# Cannot create a new reactJs application

Tags: reactjs

[Enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXdWg.jpg) I tried to create my first react js projet, but the generated file is deleted automatically

Here is the steps that I followed:

1. installed node js
2. installed npm
3. installed CRA

But, the generated file of my project is automatically deleted

Comment: try a different name, sometimes there is a package that is already called `memory` and it's conflicting. Not sure I the same can happen with react, but in react native it happens.

Comment: Try clearing npm cache "npm cache clean --force"

Comment: Also the best solution will be is to remove cache folder named '.npm' an launching console command once again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution 1:**

just try this command :

```
"npm cache clean --force"
```

**Solution 2: only windows OS**

on windows OS go to  you `AppData` file and delete `npm-cache` directory :

```
C:\Users\userName\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache
```

And re-run you create-react-app .